# How to automate a select an item from list with Appium?

Tags: appium

The app I want to test is a hybrid app developed with **AngularJS**.

I'm trying to automate a scenario with **Appium**.

To open a page with elements to select date -> today, tomorrow and pick a date.

```
<div class="item item-divider">
                <p>Select Date</p>
            </div>
<button class="button button-block button-light">Today</button>

<button class="button button-block button-light">Tomorrow</button>

<button class="button button-block button-light">Pick a date</button>
```

Let's say I select the date as today. How to automate this scenario?

[image]

Comment: Hi @comrade can you please add a screenshot of the screen and some more HTML for finding out the element.

Comment: @Antony did you manage to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this because of the classname used. 
Try the code below to get all textviews elements

```
List<WebElement> textViews = driver.findElements(By.Xpath("//*[conatains(@class,'button-block'));
```

for (WebElement textView : textViews)

```
    System.out.println( textView.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to find elements by class name and then iterate through the list. You may do something like this

```java
boolean todaysDateFound = false;

List <WebElement> days = DRIVER.findElements(By.className("button button-block button-light"));

for (int i = 0; i < days.size(); i++) {
    if (days.get(i).getAttribute("name").equals("Today")) {
        todaysDateFound = true;
        days.get(i).click;
        break;
    }
}
```

If you want to make this smarter and decide what to pick based on user input, then you can use a Select..Case statement as well.